# Comparing columns in 2 sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 excel spreadsheets,sheet 1 contains sku's in column A and cost in column E and sheet 2 contains transactions with sku's in column C.How can i get the cost in column L of spreadsheet 2 if the sku in sheet 2 matches the sku in column A of sheet 1?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1):

You want VLOOKUP. Something along the lines of:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet1!$1:$1048576,5,FALSE)
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Concerning access to cells across sheets, the [first google result](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1604/excel_how_to_reference_cells_in_other_worksheets/) I found shows that you need to use an exclamation point (and single quotes if there are spaces) to access the cell - e.g. 'Monthly Sales'!A12. Then you're left with whatever you'd have done if they were in the same sheet.